# Creating price and volume chart with flot

Tags: dynamic, flot

I have a live feed for prices and volumes of stocks traded which I'd like to graph on a web page - after looking around it seems like flot might a good choice, though I can't see any specific (code) examples for how to produce this type of chart, or how to dynamically load live data.

Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This guy seems to be using it for stocks:

http://tusacciones.com/prestadas/historico/#CIE AUTOMOT

Hopefully everything you need is there since it's Javascript...

Answer (score 1):

Here are examples on how to update Flot using AJAX:

http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/ajax.html

You could use a line chart like the examples and just change the axis increments to however often your live feed is updated.